# C# .NET async/await report progress without passing IProgress around everywhere?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, progress

Let me preface this by saying I am totally new to C# - I come from a Java background, where I haven't done much work with GUIs.

I have created a rudimentary Winforms application that has a couple of buttons which kick off some long running tasks, where those tasks themselves may or may not have a series of subtasks with indeterminate runtimes. These subtasks include API calls, downloading files, and mapping of objects from file data.

There is a single label on the main form that was previously being updated by directly accessing it from whichever function was currently running, e.g.

```
labelProgress.Text = "Beginning main long running function"; 
myClient.LongRunningFunction(); //more methods called inside this function, which update the label directly
labelProgress.Text = "Long running function is complete";
```

Obviously the problem with this is that the GUI is blocked (can't click X button, or move the window around). I know this is not the "correct" method for long running functions to update the GUI.

So now on to fixing the problem, and the root of my question - **How do I report progress in order to update my label, from multiple nested method calls, without passing an IProgress around everywhere?** All of the examples I have read only have a depth of one - by that I mean the handler starts a task, and that task then reports progress directly without handing off to other methods which themselves also need to report progress.

I basically just want to keep updating the label with meaningful status information so I can see what's happening, but it seems the only way to do that is by passing an IProgress down and down into each method call. Is there a better way to do it?

This is my top level button event handler

```
private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    MyClient client = new MyClient();
    var progress = new Progress<String>(s => labelProgress.Text = s);
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myClient.LongRunningFunction(progress), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

Then inside MyClient class

```
public async Task LongRunningFunction(IProgress<String> progress)
{
    await apiGetter.getFiles(); //async call to download some files, might want to report progress inside here later too       
    progress.Report("Processing downloaded files");
    fileProcessor.processFiles(progress); //pass the IProgress here too?
}
```

And finally the FileProcessor

```
public void processFiles(IProgress<String> progress) 
{
    //collect filenames from a predetermined location, churn through
    progress.Report("Working on file " + filename);
    doSomeStuffWithFileAndAlsoReportOnProgress(filename, progress); //again passing the IProgress down a level
    progress.Report("Done with " + filename);
}
```

Comment: Paraphrasing your question, it is "When I use a label, I have this easy way to update it by having every method directly access a field, but when I have an `IProgress<T>` how do I get around passing it down to each method?" I think the answer is obvious then, you create a class with a field for the IProgress and then every method can access it easily to call Report.

Comment: Ahhh yes of course, OK I think that gives me some ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here the 'progress property' to make reports with PropertyChanged events.

It will fix IProgress dependency issue

> without passing an IProgress around everywhere

```
public sealed class PropertyProgress<T> : IProgress<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
      public PropertyProgress(T initialProgress = default(T));

      public T Progress { get; }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: This class doesn't do anything useful because the `Progress` property is immutable, so it can never change. If `PropertyChanged` will fire events and if this class is intended to be mutable then it will introduce possible race-conditions and won't ensure the correct synchronization context is used. It's best to stick with stock `IProgress<T>`.

Comment: i'm trusting Stephen Cleary https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/PropertyProgress

Comment: Stephen's example is a class' interface, not an implementation (it's a read-only property, not a read-only auto-property), note how the constructor is not defined, only declared. He also adds the caveat that objects of that class must be instantiated on the UI thread.

Comment: sure! I think the main idea only should be put here - property to the help